# Definition of "in terms of" for a constant vs a variable

Tags: definition

Say I have a question that says:

> "answer the question in terms of x" where x is a variable.

vs.

> "answer the questions in terms of n" where n is any constant.

What is the difference between the two? ( in terms of definition )

Edit: To try and clarify, I was wondering if there was any discernible difference in the problem solving process of the two situations ( whether it be theoretical or bound by mathematical definition) . However, the  answer to the question has been given below ( referring to stonebrakermatt's and Biderman's answers ).

Comment: "( in terms of definition )" made me chuckle. :)

Comment: hahaha I didn't even notice the play on words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that a variable can represent a constant, i.e. $5x+10 = 25$. $x = 3$, so $x$ clearly is constant; however, $x$ is a variable.

When you state that $x$ is a variable, I will assume you mean something along the lines of $y = f(x)$, where $y$ can assume a range of values.

---

As Joshua said, there is no difference when it comes to problem solving.

Consider the following, where we solve for $45$ and $y$ in terms of $x$:

$5x+10 = 25 \Rightarrow 15x = 45$

$xy + 10 = 3 \Rightarrow y = \frac{-7}{x}$

In the first example, $x$ will not vary, while it will do so in the second example.

While it will not vary in way of problem-solving, the results that you yield from such a calculation are distinct. Any expression involving constants only (i.e. $\sqrt{2^{\log_34}}$) will always be a constant, no matter how complex, even if that constant is represented as a variable. This is not the case when you solve for something in terms of a *nonconstant* variable.

---

EDIT: You can often solve many types of equations in terms of an arbitrary constant, which seems to be what your example is getting at. For example, consider $x^2 \equiv 1$ (mod $10$) can give you the solutions

$x = 10n + 1$ and $x = 10n + 9$, where $n$ is any integer.

Comment: Thank you, this clarified the definition for me. I guess I was caught up in the wordiness of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, functionally there isn't. You'll solve the problems the same way. Theoretically, there's an important difference. "where n is any constant" usually means one of two things: either you're really thinking about the set of all values produced by plugging in various n, or n is a fixed but unknown number. Either way, this is theoretically distinct from a variable